# Android Studio: I have a buttons that aren't to scale on my phone?

Tags: android-studio

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_one"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.william.calculator2.MainActivity">

  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey">

  <TextView
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/one" />


<Button
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/button_1"
        android:background="@drawable/plus"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="setSubtractionOperator"/>

 <Button

        android:id="@+id/button_2"

        android:background="@drawable/minus"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />


  <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button_3"
        android:background="@drawable/one"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:onClick="useNumber1"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button_4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Yes, I realize the size for my buttons are hardcoded, I've tried to not do that but it doesn't work either way? I'm a beginner, so please don't penalize me for my mistakes, I appreciate all the help.

Here are some screenshots:

[This is in Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qypn.png)
[When run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1QcF.png)

Comment: This is in Studio is one screenshot, When run is another.

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity, in the method onClick of the button_1, you must name your method with "SetSubstractionOperator", the same name that your layout.

Comment: I'm sorry but, how will this help with the buttons display? (I'm aware the Java isn't working, I'm currently focusing on the display first)

Answer (score 0):

The hard coded width and height won't help you to scale for all screens because all screens have different quality of resolution. Try to make your drawable according to screen.

Comment: But I want it to be the same on all screens?  Not just my screen